# How to set rights to folder to upload file in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a fileupload input field that upload files to. In the matching controller method
I use the following:

```
HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile
 uploadFile.SaveAs(path);
```

But the error message I get is like this:

> Access to the path 'xxx' is denied.

I tried the following in the web.config:

```
  <identity impersonate="false" />
```

But it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is one basic think that you must check.

1. The directory access privilege on the server, probably your running pool did not allow to write on that directory.